# Openshift Origin (Minishift) - Making changes to application repository pulled on VM

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

I have installed and configured a custom Laravel private repository hosted on bitbucket  on minishift running on my laptop. I found that all the files were imported properly without any issues and the image is running.
However, now I want to make configuration changes in my repository for my application to work. How do I make it?

1. Will I have to import the image from VM on my laptop, work on them
   and then push the changes back
2. Or will I be able to access the files or folder from within my editor or IDE?

I am new to Openshift origin and using it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your source code on Bitbucket, you would checkout the repository to your local laptop, make the changes, commit them, and push them back to the repository on Bitbucket. You would then tell OpenShift to rebuild the application by clicking on the Start Build button on the build configuration details in the web console, or by using `oc start-build` on the command line, supplying it the name of the build configuration to do the build for. The rebuilding of the image from the code when done will automatically trigger a new deployment. If you set up a webhook in Bitbucket, you can have it tell OpenShift when new changes have been pushed and that will trigger a build without you needing to do it manually.

If you are quite new, I would suggest you work through the interactive tutorials at:

- https://learn.openshift.com

Also read the free eBook on OpenShift.

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and then rebuild my image. However, when running laravel app on wamp, we have to create a virtualhost and point it to public folder. I am not sure, what will we have to do in this case on minishift?

Comment: If you are using the PHP S2I builder from OpenShift, it worries about generation of the Apache configuration, you don't have to. You can control some aspects of how it works by setting environment variables on the OpenShift deployment configuration. See https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-php-container/tree/master/7.0

Comment: Thanks. I would go through the documentation in detail and then configure it. Also since, my primary question was resolved, I would close this question.